# how to refresh the kendo grid once $scope.gridOptions get new data

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am new to kendo grid
i have assign data to kendo grid inside service call 
i have search field in the html form, whenever type number and press search service will called, the new data will bind to $scope.gridOptions.dataSource.data  but in view screen the new data not shown.

```
                'use strict';
            angular
                .module('app.core')
                .controller('CheckController', function($scope,PageValues,eventService,$filter,$timeout) {

                var vm = this;
                PageValues.title = "Check";
                PageValues.description = "Check";


                $scope.checkStatus = function(){


                    if($scope.phone_number != ''){
                        var chkPostRequest = {
                            "checkContacts": [
                                {

                                    "Date": '2011=02-01',
                                    "Type": "test"
                                    "Category": 'test'
                                }
                            ]
                        };
                        eventService.checkStatusSer(chkPostRequest).then(function(response){
                                if(angular.lowercase(response.transactionStatus) == "success"){
                                $scope.gridOptions = {};
                                    response.checkContactResponses.forEach(function(contStatus, key) {
                                        $scope.chkStsRes.checkContactResponses[key] = {
                                            "PhoneNumber" : contStatus.contactDetail.contact,
                                            "phoneType" : contStatus.phoneType
                                        };
                                    });
                                    $scope.gridOptions = {
                                        dataSource: {
                                           data: $scope.chkStsRes.checkContactResponses,
                                            schema: {
                                                model: {
                                                    fields: {
                                                        PhoneNumber: { type: "string" } ,
                                                        PhoneNumberType: { type: "string" },
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            pageSize: 10
                                        },

                                        scrollable: true,
                                        sortable: true,
                                        columns: [
                                            { field: "PhoneNumber", title: "Phone Number",  width: "130px",cellFilter: 'phonemask'},
                                            { field: "PhoneNumberType", title: "Phone Number Type", width: "80px" },
                                        ]
                                    };
                                   $scope.mygrid.refresh();
                                }
                        });
                    }
                }
                });
```

HTML code

```
<input required id="phone_number" ng-model="phone_number" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;" value=""/>
<button class="btn" ng-click="checkStatus()" type="button" ><span>Check Status</span></button>
<kendo-grid options="gridOptions" id="searchGrid"></kendo-grid>
```

Response json

```
        {            
          "transactionStatus": "SUCCESS",
          "checkContactResponses": [
            {
              "phoneType": "Mobile",
              "contactDetail": {
                "contact": "3341234567"
              }
            },
            {
              "phoneType": "Landline",
              "contactDetail": {
                "contact": "3346543210"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

response json is modofied whenever i click button
How can i refresh are reload kendo grid, whenever the service call hits.

Answer (score 0):

You assign a variable to the `kendo-grid` attribute, which you can then use to call the normal kendo functions. For example:

```
<div kendo-grid="mygrid" options="gridOptions" id="searchGrid"></div>
```

Now, within your controller, you can refresh the grid like this:

```
$scope.mygrid.refresh();
```

Here is a simple fiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/JX0S08cfKDERMwkLaKPs

Comment: i got this issue  :  "Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined"

Comment: Then you haven't correctly bound the `kendo-grid` to a variable. Are you calling it on the right `$scope`? Did you try and copy what the fiddle is doing?

Comment: My html like this only now <div kendo-grid="mygrid" options="gridOptions" id="searchGrid"></div>

Comment: Then you are probably using the wrong `$scope`. Show more of your controller, service, and template code and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I have added full controller, short of html and json, please see the changes in above question.

Comment: I don't see any call to `$scope.mygrid.refresh()`... It should be after you update the `$scope.gridOptions` variable.

Comment: I have added but its not work through undefined error